# CSV export prints complete HTML

Tags: php, csv, export

I have this export button that needs to xport data fro my database to an excel(csv) file but when i press itthe complete html is shown in the csv file.

here is my ode for the export:

```
if (isset($_POST["export"])) {
    header('Content-Type: text/csv; charset=utf-8');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=data.csv');
    $output = fopen("php://output", "w");
    fputcsv($output, array('example','example','example','example','example','example','example','example','example','example'));
    $query = "SELECT example,example,example,example,example,example,example,example,example,example FROM user";
    $stmt = $con->prepare($query);
    $stmt->execute();
    fclose($output);
    exit();
}
```

**Edit:**

This is my complete file with the code in it, i tried both options that were given below and they didn't seem to work. It still prints the complete html into a csv file.

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST["export"])) {
    header('Content-Type: text/csv; charset=utf-8');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=data.csv');
    $output = fopen("php://output", "w");
      fputcsv($output, array('example','example','example','example','example','example','example','example','example','example'));
    $query = "SELECT example,example,example,example,example,example,example,example,example,example FROM user";
    $stmt = $con->prepare($query);
    $stmt->execute();
    fclose($output);
    exit();
}
print '<div class="dropdown">
    <button class="dropbtn">Kies een Lijst... <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i> </button>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="index.php?pages=lijst_een">Gehele Lijst</a>
      <a href="index.php?pages=lijst_twee">Namen/Social/Soort</a>
      <a href="index.php?pages=lijst_drie">Namen & Soort</a>
      <a href="index.php?pages=lijst_vier">Soort</a>
      <a href="index.php?pages=lijst_vijf">Namen & Categorie Bordspellen</a>
      <a href="index.php?pages=lijst_zes">Namen & Categorie Bordspellen</a>
      <a href="index.php?pages=lijst_zeven">Namen</a>
    </div>
  </div> ';
function getKeys($con, $query)
{
    $result = $con->query($query);
    $row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    return array_keys($row);
}

function getValues($con, $query)
{
    $data = $con->query($query);
    $data->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    return $data;
}

$query = "SELECT example,example,example,example,example,example,example,example,example,example FROM user";
//Tabel 1
print "<table id='een'>";
$array_keys = getKeys($con, $query);

print " <tr>";
foreach ($array_keys as $value) {
    print " <th>$value</th>";
}
print " </tr> ";

//Values
$data = getValues($con, $query);
foreach ($data as $row) {
    print " <tr> ";
    foreach ($row as $name => $value) {
        print " <td>$value</td> ";
    }
    print " </tr> ";
}
print '<form method="post" action="index.php?pages=export1"><button type="submit" name="export" value="export" style="width: 5%; height: 5%">Export</button></form>';
//export to csv

print "</table> ";
print '
<footer class="w3-center footer" style="margin-top: 25%">
    <div class="w3-xlarge w3-section">
        <?php $_SESSION["loggedin"] = true;
        if ($_SESSION["loggedin"] === true) {
            ?>
            <h6><br>&copy Big Bang 2020<a href="index.php?pages=uitloggen" id="uitloggen"> Uitloggen</a></h6>
            <?php
        }
        ?>
    </div>
</footer>';
```

**Edit 2**

maybe it helps that i show the result in the csv file.
csv file:
[image]
The header is a header.php file which is included in the index.php file automatically.

Comment: Without further context we can't say exactly why, but at a guess, is there some PHP code and/or HTML markup included _before_ this code appears in your script?

Comment: Yes there is php code, and html code printed in php

Answer (score 0):

If you have other PHP and HTML in your script located earlier than the code shown, then that content will still be output by PHP - everything in the script will be output unless you specifically instruct it not to be. And you've decided to redirect all that output to a file download, so the result is inevitable - all the output goes into the file.

You need to make sure that other content doesn't get output when the user has chosen the export option. This is simple enough:

Either:

1. Just put the `if (isset($_POST["export"])) {`
   as the first line of the script so that nothing else is output first. The script will already end after that due to your `exit()` command, so no other output would then be included in the download. (If you also have a header file which outputs HTML included before this, then this option won't be sufficient, you'll need to use the second option below - which is arguably a better separation of concerns anyway.)

OR

2. put the export code into a separate PHP script which doesn't have any other purpose or function, then there is no danger of other content being accidentally included in the file. Whatever form you are using to request the export should be changed to post back to that script instead.

Comment: Thank you, i will try both of them, i will let you know it it worked

Comment: both options did not work, so i guess there is something wrong with the export code but i don't know what's wrong with it

Comment: I can't see how it's possible, to be honest, based on what you've shown. I mean if you moved the `if (isset($_POST["export"])) { ... }` section to a separate PHP file called `export.php` which contained no other code at all, and then changed your form to `action="export.php"` then I can't really see how it could possibly include any HTML in there. The only other thing I can think of is, by any chance do you have header files included in your script before the bit you've shown? If so, does the header file(s) output HTML?

Comment: Yes there is, well, not in that file , but the header is always included on the index.php page.

Comment: That would explain it then. You definitely need a separate script file to do the export. And make sure the separate script doesn't include the header code.

Comment: i dont think that will work either because it prints the values from the array in the csv file too, so think if i do that only the header will be excluded but my database content wont show

Comment: Well the code you've shown does only put the sample array into the file, that's true. The SQL query you've written isn't used for anything currently. But I assumed that was just an example for the sake of the question. You will obviously need to adapt your current code to insert all the rows from the database into the code. But that has nothing to do with using a separate script or removing the header.